# HTTPS Client Certificate Request freezes when the Server is handling a large PUT/POST Request

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, resttemplate, tls1.2

I'm trying to establish two-way mutual handshaking between client and server where the server uses TLS. API from server accepts file through post request and client is configured with keystore, and was able to send files that are less than 50kb. API started breaking with `Borken Pipe` error while sending larger than 50kb. I found a link [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Networking-Blog/HTTPS-Client-Certificate-Request-freezes-when-the-Server-is/ba-p/339672) which talks about the similar issue.

As suggested by the article, I have modified the code to send a get request to establish a secure connection before sending the original request with file. Still the problem persist and giving the same error.

Client setup:

```
@Bean
    @DependsOn(value = {"customRestTemplateCustomizer"})
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        try {
            return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                    .requestFactory(this::clientHttpRequestFactory)
                    .rootUri(properties.getBaseUrl())
                    .errorHandler(new RestTemplateErrorHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception thrown while setting ssl context : {} ", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
        return httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    HttpClient httpClient() {
        SSLContext sslContext = sslContext();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = socketFactory(sslContext);
        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @SneakyThrows
    public SSLContext sslContext(){
        return new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStore), keyStorePassword.toCharArray(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray())

                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory(SSLContext sslContext) {
        return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    }

    static {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> hostname.equals(url));
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomRestTemplateCustomizer customRestTemplateCustomizer() {
        return new CustomRestTemplateCustomizer();
    }
```

get call to establish connection call:

```
//get call before making actual call
  String response = restTemplate.getForObject("www.getapi.com", String.class);
```

//actual call

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            headers.setConnection("keep-alive");

MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            body.add("SigningId", signingId);
            body.add("Payload", new StreamedFile(inputStream, fileName));
            body.add("Payload Hash", hashValue);
            body.add("Callback URL", callbackURL);

ResponseEntity<Response> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                    outgoingURL,
                    new HttpEntity<>(body, headers),
                    Response.class);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "www.postapi.com": null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException] with root cause

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:879) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:160) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:120) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.lambda$execute$1(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest$StreamingHttpEntity.writeTo(HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:152) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo(RequestEntityProxy.java:123) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
```

As I thought httpclient is closing the connection for every request, i have added

```
headers.setConnection("keep-alive");
```

but it didn't work. I tried searching about httpconnecton closing but many people say by defaut it re-uses the same connection as a session.

Unfortunately server code is written python and I do not have any idea about its implementation. It is working for files less than 50kb so my security configuration is good.

Comment: Any chances you are behind old version of apache httpd?

Comment: Maybe the server has an explicit limit on the size of a POST request and closes the connection for larger bodies? This would not be unusual. Or maybe there is an implicit limit in that the server crashes because of some out of memory? In both cases this would result in the Broken Pipe you see since the server socket is closed but the client is still sending data. And disabling or enabling HTTP keep-alive would not make any difference in such cases.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich server has a limit of 2GB files and I'm only sending about 100kb. To prove that I have got a program written in python from the client people and was able to run it from my local without any issues

Comment: Broken pipe means that the server has closed the connection. Given that you seem to have contact to the people responsible for the server side please ask them why their server closes the connection for your client while your client is not done sending data.

Comment: As this is working for smaller files and program written in another language, they claims the client is closing the connection it established as part of the get request and failing because the client certificate struck in the buffer when original request is made.

Comment: A broken pipe is not a freeze. It is an error, and a properly written application will recover from it.

Comment: @arjun: *"... they claims the client is closing the connection it established as part of the get request and failing because the client certificate struck in the buffer when original request is made"* - this does not make any sense at all, i.e. maybe they are wrong or you did understand them wrong.  Again, a broken pipe is caused by writing to a socket which is closed by the server.

Comment: @user207421 did you mean the client failed to handle the error? can you point me if there could be anything to add to my code

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried searching and found different answers for the question "Does resttemplate closes connection for every request?". Also why the server was able to process the same file which was sent with the code written in python but throwing broken pipe?

Comment: @arjun: Nothing in your question or comment suggested so far that the server was able to process the **same** file but only that it was able a large request from a client written in Python. Even then same file does not mean same request. There is nothing known about the Python program except that it works. There is nothing known about the server except that it works for the Python program but not for yours with large requests. It is impossible to compare anything based on this lack of information. And again, broken pipe means that the server has closed the connection - ask why it did this.